# How to fetch two related objects in Laravel (Eloquent) with one SQL query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get two related objects in Laravel using eager loading as per documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

My models are:

```
class Lead extends Model {
  public function session() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\LeadSession');
  }
}

class LeadSession extends Model {
  public function lead() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Lead');
  }
}
```

I want to get both objects with one SQL query. Basically I want to execute:

```
select * from lead_sessions as s 
inner join lead as l 
on l.id = s.lead_id 
where s.token = '$token';
```

and then be able to access both the LeadSession and Lead objects. Here is the php code I am trying:

```
$lead = Lead::with(['session' => function ($q) use ($token) {
  $q->where('token','=',$token);
}])->firstOrFail();

print($lead->session->id);
```

I have also tried:

```
$lead = Lead::whereHas('session', function($q) use ($token) {
  $q->where('token','=',$token);
})->firstOrFail();

print($lead->session->id);
```

and

```
$session = LeadSession::with('lead')->where('token',$token)->firstOrFail();

print($session->lead->id);
```

In all three cases I get two queries executed, one for the `leads` table, and another for the `lead_sessions` table.

Is such a thing possible in Eloquent? In my view it should be a standard ORM operation, but for some reason I am struggling a whole day with it.

I don't want to use the Query Builder because I want to use the Eloquent objects and their functions afterwards.

I am coming from Python and Django and I want to replicate the behavior of `select_related` function in Django.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, you want `Eloquent` to only produce 1 query instead or 2?

Comment: @RossWilson, yes. Both models can be retrieved using a join query

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see if it makes more than one query

```
$session = LeadSession::join('leads', 'leads.id', '=', 'lead_sessions.lead_id')
->where('token',$token)
->firstOrFail();
```

I hope it only runs a single query. I didnt test this. Not sure if you have to add a `select()` to pick the columns. But yeah, try this first.

**Updates**
Just adding how to use both session and lead data. Try a select and specify the data you need. The reason being that if both tables have similar columns like 'id', one of them will be overwritten. So you have to alias your select like

```
$session = LeadSession::join('leads', 'leads.id', '=', 'lead_sessions.lead_id')
->where('token',$token)
->select(
    'lead_sessions.*',
    'leads.id as lead_id',
    'leads.name',
    'leads.more_stuff'
)
->firstOrFail();
```

Now all this data belongs to `$session` variable. For testing you were doing

```
print($lead->session->id);
//becomes 
print($session->lead_id); //we aliased this in the query
```

Comment: `$session->lead->id` is the one making the query through eager loading. Read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading the query is made when you write that for the first time. What I was proposing was for you to get all the data in one go then use without eager loading.

Comment: I have removed the eager loading code, still the same.
it first executes one query with a join:
`select * from lead_sessions inner join leads on leads.id = lead_sessions.lead_id where token = ?`
and then goes onto executing another one:
`select * from leads where leads.id = ?`

Comment: yes, I have edited my previous comment, and added both queries that execute on the print. After the print I have a die(), so it stops.

Comment: I have to admit you have a pretty complexe use case. It's a good challenge, but I have to admit I can't see a way to do that in one query using Eloquent.

Comment: not a pretty complex use case. I just want to optimize the db operations in the application. The actual action is more complex and it joins four related models so I want to get them all in one query instead of executing four. It should be quite a common operation for an ORM.

Comment: I think EddyTheDove solution only runs 1 query instead of 2. The presence of the second query is likely due to the use of 'with'.

Comment: @LCYoong, I am running only the `$session = LeadSession::join(...)` statement and I get two queries when I try to print `$session->lead->id`. If I print only `$session->id`, then I get only one query. I am checking the queries in the mysql general log

Comment: @MartinTaleski and you are both right. My solution only runs a single query. Your second query from `$session->lead->id`. You are loading a `lead` separately.

Comment: so do you think if there is a way to load session and lead in one query, not separately?

Comment: My join already does that. You already have leads inside the result of my query. But, you were trying to use eager loading, which is why I gave up because eager loading ALWAYS run at least one extra query. No way it doesn't run additional queries. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @EddyTheDove, ok I understand that the join takes data from both tables, but when I try to access the data from the second table through the Eloquent model, the ORM executes another query, instead of taking the data from what it already has in PHP memory. I have removed the eager loading code, I only execute your statement and a print afterwards, nothing else.

Comment: @MartinTaleski, you don't need eager loading in this instance and u can just access the id directly via $session->id. If both tables share a common id field, simply alias the join table.

Comment: @EddyTheDove, I am not using the eager loading `with` function, I am using the code that you wrote. Your code creates a `$session` variable which holds the Session object. How do I get the Lead object from there, without calling another SQL? I don't need just the id, I need the whole Lead object with its functions. I am using the `print($session->lead->id);` just to test if it calls another query.

Comment: I made some updates for you to see how to access the data without eager loading.

Comment: @EddyTheDove, I am not able to access the Lead object from your solution. I don't just need the columns from the lead table, I need the whole Eloquent Lead object and all of its methods. `$session->lead_id;` gives me only the `lead_id`

Comment: Please for the love of all things, just take a look at the `attributes` from that query. `$session->lead_id` or `$session->name` hold the clues you need.

Comment: @DavidBarker, how does `$session->lead_id` give me the Lead object?

Comment: It doesn't and won't. As soon as you start using the query builder outside of eloquent you receive the attributes you ask for, e.g. leads.name.

Comment: @DavidBarker, but I don't want only the attributes I want the functions from the model as well, which hold the business logic

Comment: Well just use the native eager loading methods. What's the big deal with two SQL queries?